# Which mimAmsa texts consider looking at sanyasins as sinful?

Tags: purva-mimamsa, vedic-rituals, sannyasa

Quoting from the [chapter "Mimangsa beliefs" of the book Hindu Dharma](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part12/chap9.htm):

> The sannyasin deprives himself of karma ('karma- bhrashta'). To look
>   at him is sinful and you must atone for it. To look at the sinner, to
>   talk to him, to dine with him, " say Mandanamisra and mimamsakas like,
>   "is to earn sin. To look at a sanyasin is equally sinful. "

Even many of vaishnavas avoid looking at sanyasins who have shaved their heads and abandoned the sacred thread.

I want to know the references from the mimamsa texts or any other scriptures that talk of the above mentioned points?